# How would I create a POJO class for such a data structure?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap, pojo

My data structure in firestore database is supposed to look like this

[image]

As from the image, the `our_array` field, is an array that contains fields of data type - Map inside it.

I need to create a simple POJO in order to insert the data as designed.

My current POJO class:

```
class ProductList{
  private boolean availability;
  private Object[] our_array; //I have doubts about this one
  private String product_title;

  … //Getters & setters
}
```

How can I structure the above data set, spefically the `our_maps` array that contains Map(s) inside it?

Comment: just like you created a pojo for productlist, create another pojo for product and instead of having an array of **Object[]** ProductList should contain an array of **Product[]**, inside product you can keep maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a Product pojo :

```
class Product {
  private String productName;
  … 
  …
  // getters / setters
}
```

then your ProductList class could have a list of Products instead :

```
class ProductList {
  private boolean availability;
  private List<Product> our_productList; 
  ...
  //Getters & setters
}
```